# Horizontal scrolling not working in macOS calendar app

Tags: calendar, trackpad, accessibility, macos

I have scrolling problems very often with the calendar app on macOS.
It works "a bit" but get stuck into the current week, **scrolling left or right will just bump but not scroll**, driving me insane.

You can see something about that here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7954399

[image]

Although the solution enunciated there works, it's very inefficient and boring procedure to do.

Comment: Could you please summarize here what the linked fix is? I don’t see it there, thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A stupid and so simple solution, which for months (if not years...) I didn't think about, is **simply to right click in the calendar app** (with the same two fingers you use to scroll).

And that's it, problem gone!

Comment: This was stupidly simple and worked for me too in MacOS Monterey. Bug was driving me nuts! Crazy. I'm sure a reboot would have worked too, but now I can delay the inevitable, haha. Thanks!

Comment: This works for me too on Monterey. But how did you even discover this and why does this work lmao

Comment: Thanks so much! That bug was also driving me crazy. I had even restarted the calendar app!

Comment: Yeah even restarting  Calendar.app didn't work, but this did. Some weird kernel/  driver bug it feels like

Answer (score 9):

Rebooting works for me, though I'm glad to learn the workaround you linked to.

For posterity, the workaround was to go to:

System Preferences > Accessibility > Mouse & Trackpad > Trackpad Options...

and toggle the scrolling settings and shown in the picture.

[image]

UPDATE FOR VENTURA 2022+:

System Settings, Accessibility, Pointer Control, Trackpad Options…, and toggle off/on Use trackpad for scrolling.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works for me in macOS Ventura, combined with right clicking the calendar app as described in another answer. In macOS Ventura the setting is at System Settings > Accessibility > Pointer Control > Trackpad Options > Use inertia when scrolling.

Comment: Fixed month view not scrolling for me on macOS 13.1 (Ventura) by toggling "Use trackpad for scrolling"

Answer (score 0):

For the trackpad I see the selection box to tick on scrolling - but not for the mouse ... see picture.[image]